# Redis service is running, but stops writing logs after sometime and keys are vanished

Tags: redis

I have redis 3.2.8 up and running with default conf file in my ubuntu system. After sometime time it was unable to write to dump.rdb file and even no logs in the log file from that time, but service is still up and running. 'Keys *' giving me few number of keys which are created after that time. Why it was unable to read and write from/to the dump.rdb file, what might be the issue?

Comment: To ask the obvious, did any of those missing keys have expiry times assigned to them?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen no, keys are there in rdb file, after restarting the redis-server i am getting those keys back, problem is it is unable to read and write from rdb file